# Ansible playbook json_query

Tags: ansible, json-query

After having loaded the following Ansible local facts :

```
    {
    "cdbs": {
        "e01ca601": {
            "char_set": "AL32UTF8",
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_1",
            "npdbs": "1",
            "pdbs": "pdb1"
        },
        "e01ca602": {
            "char_set": "WE8ISO8859P1",
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_2",
            "npdbs": "0",
            "pdbs": ""
        },
        "e01ca603": {
            "char_set": "AL32UTF8",
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_3",
            "npdbs": "0",
            "pdbs": ""
        },
        "e01ca604": {
            "char_set": "WE8ISO8859P1",
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_1",
            "npdbs": "0",
            "pdbs": ""
        },
        "e01ca605": {
            "char_set": "AL32UTF8",
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_2",
            "npdbs": "0",
            "pdbs": ""
        },
        "e01ca900": {
            "char_set": "WE8ISO8859P1",
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_3",
            "npdbs": "1",
            "pdbs": "pdb2"
        }
    },
    "pdbs": {
        "pdb1": {
            "cdb": "e01ca601",
            "creation_time": "2020-01-21 14:10:39"
        },
        "pdb2": {
            "cdb": "e01ca900",
            "creation_time": "2020-01-13 13:34:21"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use them in a filter to select only on e.g. cdbs.*.char_set == 'AL32UTF8', but am not able to figure out how to add the filter condition in a task:

```
- name: "Task1"
  vars:
    myquery : '[cdbs.*.char_set][0]'
  debug:
    msg:
      - "Query condition: {{ myquery }}"
      - "Query filter   : {{ ansible_local | json_query(myquery) }}"
```

In addition to this would it be possible to get a list of names of the items, i.e. e01ca605 etc ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards, Dirk

Answer (score 1):

I got this (using a pipe) to work:

```
- name: "Task4"
  vars:
    myquery: cdbs.* | [?char_set=='AL32UTF8']
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_local | json_query(myquery)  }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: Select cdbs.*.char_set == 'AL32UTF8'

A: The tasks below

```
    - set_fact:
        sel_AL32UTF8: "{{ cdbs|json_query(myquery) }}"
      vars:
        myquery: "*|[?char_set=='AL32UTF8']"
    - debug:
        var: sel_AL32UTF8
```

give

```
   "sel_AL32UTF8": [
        {
            "char_set": "AL32UTF8", 
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_3", 
            "npdbs": "0", 
            "pdbs": ""
        }, 
        {
            "char_set": "AL32UTF8", 
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_1", 
            "npdbs": "1", 
            "pdbs": "pdb1"
        }, 
        {
            "char_set": "AL32UTF8", 
            "home": "/u01/dbhome_2", 
            "npdbs": "0", 
            "pdbs": ""
        }
    ]
```

---

> Q: Get a list of names.

A: Apply the `keys()` method. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        cdbs_keys: "{{ cdbs.keys()|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: cdbs_keys
```

give

```
    "cdbs_keys": [
        "e01ca900", 
        "e01ca602", 
        "e01ca603", 
        "e01ca601", 
        "e01ca604", 
        "e01ca605"
    ]
```

Comment: Hello Vladimir, 

your proposed tasks work just fine!

In the meantime I also got this (using a pipe) to work:

    - name: "Task4"
      vars:
        myquery: cdbs.* | [?char_set=='AL32UTF8']
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ ansible_local | json_query(myquery)  }}"

However, would it be possible to get a list of names of the items, i.e. e01ca605 etc ?

cheers, Dirk

Comment: Hello Dirk. Sure, I've updated the answer. Cheers, Vladimir.

Comment: Hello Vladimir,

thanks this works fine as well. The idea is to combine these two:

get the list of keys for the filter condition. Do you have a solution for this as well?

Thanks & cheers, Dirk

Comment: added solution to this question in the answer section

Answer (score 0):

finally, combining Vladimir's replies the solution found is:

```
    - name: "Task10"
  vars:
    myquery: "[?value.char_set=='AL32UTF8']"
  debug: var=item.key
  with_items: "{{ ansible_local.cdbs|dict2items|json_query(myquery) }}"
```

resulting in a list of items

```
ok: [exa101vm01] => (item={'key': u'e01ca900', 'value': {u'home': u'/u01/dbhome_1', u'npdbs': u'1', u'char_set': u'AL32UTF8', u'pdbs': u'pdb1', u'archivelog_mode': u'NOARCHIVELOG'}}) => {
"ansible_loop_var": "item",
"item": {
    "key": "e01ca900",
    "value": {
        "archivelog_mode": "NOARCHIVELOG",
        "char_set": "AL32UTF8",
        "home": "/u01/dbhome_1",
        "npdbs": "1",
        "pdbs": "pdb1"
    }
},
"item.key": "e01ca900"
} 
... (cut here)
```

Syntax and possibilities seem quite powerful, however difficult to debug ;-)

Thanks for your help!

Cheers, Dirk